# Executing dynamically added social network widgets

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, liferay, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm currently developing a portlet in Liferay 6.2. In the portlets configuration I store social network names and their scripts (the ones provided by the different social netoworks, such as Facebook, Twitter... etc).

When it comes to the public portlet, I have different tabs, one for each stored social network (so the number of them is variable). When I initially load the portlet I have no problem in showing the Facebook page plugin, but when I start changing tabs, there is a problem. I bring the social network scripts (html + script tags).

I know that if you insert that pieces of code, the script tags won't be executed, so I won't have the loaded plugins on the portlet, just the html. If I eval() the script, Facebook script does not work at all, and it does not show any error. If I change Facebooks script tag with my own code and then eval() it, it works, but if I stay with Facebooks code, nothing happens.

```
A.io.request(portletURL.toString(),{
            on: {
              success: function() {
                var data = this.get('responseData');
                var cont = document.getElementById('contenedor-script');
                document.getElementById('contenedor-script').innerHTML = data;
                var arr = document.getElementById('contenedor-script').getElementsByTagName('script')
                for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++){
                    console.log(arr[n].innerHTML);
                    eval(arr[n].innerHTML) //this executes the script tag
                }
              }
            }
          });
```

Now comes the script that is being inserted:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/www.oviedo.es/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/www.oviedo.es/">Facebook</a></blockquote></div>
```

When the function is not being evaluated, the html markup is being showed.

My alternative is to load all the tabs at the beggining and start showing and hiding them with CSS, but it is a worse idea.

Thanks.

Comment: `eval`  is  **evil**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the Plugins again with `FB.XFBML.parse()`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Call that function as soon as the elements are rendered in the browser and the JavaScript SDK will parse/show them.

Btw, you should only load the JS SDK once, of course. And don´t ever use "eval"...

Comment: Just one question, will it work if I start adding other social networks? I mean, not only Facebook. Because I had tried with Facebook and it worked perfectly, but does not seem to work with Twitter after adding its script.

What I'm looking for is a generic method for all social networks, what I found were only particular solutions.

Comment: FB.XFBML.parse is for facebook plugins only, of course. it´s a methode from the JavaScript SDK. other platforms may have a different solution for it. there is no generic method.